# Laravel Auth::user dynamic variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I realize that I am writing the same code over and over again in my Jquery and am wondering if their is a way to use a variable so I don't have to basically copy and past again and again with minor changes.

Here is my code

```
function checkValueOfRole()
      {
          var role = "{!! Auth::user()->role !!}";
          $("#role" + " option[value='" + role + "']").prop('selected', true);
          if(role)
          {
              $('#roleCheck').show();
          }
      }
```

But instead of role, it can be replaced with subrole, goal, etc.  Replacing the javascript I know how to do. What I am struggling is how to replace the Auth::user()->role with Auth::user()->variable.  Is their a way to do this?

What I am wondering if their is a way to use a variable to replace what comes after Auth::user()->.  So instead of using Auth::user()->role or Auth::user()->subrole.  I can use Auth::user()->variable.

Comment: Question not clear.

Comment: @AmitGupta, I added a line is the question and clearer?

Comment: Add it once outside of the function. It will be available inside of the functions.

Comment: Sorry, misread the question. Would the variable be defined your PHP, or your javascript?

Comment: @aynber the PHP variable

Answer (score 0):

It's actually quite simple:

```
$var = 'role';
Auth::user()->$var;
```

Comment: @Aaron What does "broke" mean?

Comment: Sorry about that I get an error Undefined variable: var

Comment: @Aaron Well, you need to define the $var first.

Comment: Right, but how do I take a javascript variable and assign its value to a php variable?  Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

You would define `$myVar` somewhere in a blade template, and then, somewhere else in the same template, or in an `@include()` you would use:

```
function checkValueOfRole()
{
    var role = "{!! Auth::user()->$myVar !!}";
    ...
}
```